# php log in with session display

Tags: php, session

Hi I am trying to make a website prototype that will show log in username , i have successfully displayed the user session, but when there is no session it will only display error.

```
<h1>Dear Precious Customer</h1>
<div>
  <h4> Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> </h4>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
```

Here is my code for the display, as you can see it only show when session is active , if there is no session it will only show error . Instead of that error, how do I make it display something like "welcome log in or register" thanks.

Comment: _it only show when session is active_ nope ,do `echo isset($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION['username'] : 'log in or register';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
<div><h4>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];  ?></h4></div>
```

To

```
<?php
 $msg = 'Welcome! <a href="login.html">Login</a> | <a href="register.html">Register</a>';
 if ($_SESSION && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   $msg = 'Welcome! ' .$_SESSION['username'];
}
?>
<div><h4><?php echo $msg;?></h4></div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks !! , its working , now is it possible to put hypertext link on a php ? thanks a million again !

Comment: Updated my answer.... where I created login and register as hyperlink....
Accept my answer if it helped you ...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to test for the session variable like,

```
<div><h4>Welcome <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : 'Register');  ?></h4></div>
```

That way if it's not set, you simply output the other desired string.